# Correctness of my attempt on writing down the lyrics of Trapeze's "Midnight Flyer" song

Tags: lyrics, rock

As a Trapeze fan, finding lyrics to most of their songs on the internet is quite difficult (if not impossible), and trying to make a transcription of the song's vocals has proven to be sometimes difficult for a non-native english speaker like me.

This is my best attempt so far:

**Midnight Flyer - Trapeze - Hot Wire(1974)**

- Verse 1:

  We're all gonna meet there
  It worked out fine
   
  No stipulations
  We've chosen our minds

  Get down to the good times
   
  We're gonna have a ball
  Get down to the music
  We'll ride down our falls(?)
- Verse 2:

  Pull down on the (cherners?)
   
  Open up your doors
   
  The world needs love
  So what we waiting for

  Getting right information
   
  Getting in time
   
  It won't be easy
   
  Still we gotta try
- Chorus:

   Fly, Midnight Flyer
   Fly, Take it Higher (Higher!) x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I hear:

Verse 1:

We're all gonna meet there 
It worked out fine 
No stipulations 
We've chosen our minds

Get down to the good times 
We're gonna have a ball 
**And get** down to the music 
We'll ride on [palls??]

Verse 2:

Pull down on the [churners??] 
Open **all the** doors 
The world needs love 
So what we waiting for

Getting right information 
Getting in time 
It won't be easy 
Still we gotta try

Chorus:
Fly, Midnight Flyer 
Fly, Take it Higher (Higher!) x2

There's not much else I can say though as a music producer. The singers just weren't enunciating in a clear enough way sometimes, or the production contributed to the loss of treble clarity that is crucial to understanding sibilant syllables. \'~'/

Answer (score 0):

I hear “pull down the shutters” ??? Open all the doors.